# Uploading picture using PXImageUploader

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to upload image on my custom page and following are the code in aspx source

```
<px:PXImageUploader ID="edImageUrl" runat="server" AlreadyLocalized="False" DataField="ImageUrl" DefaultLocale="" AllowNoImage="True"  FlexRatio="False" MagnifyDefault="False" ShowComment="False" ViewOnly="False" AllowUpload="True"  Height="320px" Width="430px" DataMember="lotserailrec" >
                </px:PXImageUploader>
```

The image uploads and attached to custom page if I drag and drop on the image and it is not uploading through file selection.

Comment: I do recall this issue in an old version of Acumatica. What version are you running?

Comment: Acumatica Version : 6.10.0472

Comment: That version should be good. I think the issue i had was back in a 5.2 version. We have a page that does this. Going to confirm in 6.10.0680

Comment: Works in 6.10.0680. This is what our page entry looks like and maybe simplifying the page entry it might solve your issue?
  <px:PXImageUploader Height="375px" Width="375px" ID="imgUploader" runat="server" DataField="ImageUrl" AllowUpload="true" ShowComment="true" DataMember="MyCustomRecordsSelected"/>

Comment: The issue is due to NoteId Column in Extension Table. I have moved it to main table and now the picture is uploading

Comment: That was my guess (note field in extension table). When you said move to main table... you added a UsrNoteID field? (if not what did you change? maybe best to write what you did as an answer to your own question for others to see)